# Performing an efficient query on a many to many relationship in EF Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In Entity Framework Core one can setup a [many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) relationship via a join table.

I don't know how to query a relationship like this in an efficient way. Given the reference relationships below, I have, a `Post` entity and the `PostTags` collection is null. I want to load all the `Tag`s associated with the `Post` and the best I have so far is something that looks like this:

```
void GetAllTags(Post somePost)
{
    await dbContext.Entry(somePost)
        .Collection(p => p.PostTags)
        .LoadAsync();
    foreach(var postTag in somePost.PostTags)
    {
        await dbContext.Entry(postTag)
            .Reference(p => p.Tag)
            .LoadAsync();
    }
}
```

I really would prefer to return an `ICollection<Tag>` via a single query to the DB.

---

This is the reference implementation from [Relationships - EF Core | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.PostId, t.TagId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Post)
            .WithMany(p => p.PostTags)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.PostId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Tag)
            .WithMany(t => t.PostTags)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TagId);
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string TagId { get; set; }

    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class PostTag
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need is to *get* a list of the tags associated with a post, you can use simple projection query. Just make sure to start with a `DbSet<>` (i.e. EF Core `IQueryable<>`) rather than materialized object / collection, e.g.

```
ICollection<Tag> GetAllTags(Post somePost)
{
    return await dbContext.Set<PostTag>()
        .Where(pt => pt.PostId == somePost.PostId)
        .Select(pt => pt.Tag)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

If you indeed want to *load* them into the passed `Post` entity instance, you can use a combination of explicit and eager loading via `Query` method:

```
void LoadAllTags(Post somePost)
{
    await dbContext.Entry(somePost)
        .Collection(p => p.PostTags)
        .Query()
        .Include(pt => pt.Tag)
        .LoadAsync();
}
```

Comment: Why do I need to start with a dbSet? I had come up with a `dbContext.Entry(somePost).Collection(p=>p.PostTags).Query().Include(j=>j.Tag).ThenInclude(t=>t.someOtherFKProp).Select(j=>j.Tag)` to do the query (with a recursive join to a 3rd table). Is this going to fail?

Comment: That's another way - `.Entry(…).Collection(…).Query()` provides the same `IQueryable<>` as  `Set<>().Where(…)` I used. The difference is that the `DbSet` approach does not need `somePost` to be attached (tracked) by the context while `Entry(somePost)` will definitely attach the `somePost` to the context.